# JTable HTML Font Display Problem with JRE 6U24

Tags: java, html, swing, applet, japplet

In my JApplet program,I'd like to make the color of one cell of JTable to BLUE.
Though there has many methods to do it.One method I think easy is to use HTML tag.
But it only works well when firstly access the JApplet with JRE 6u24.
operation as follows:

1.open the JApplet.You can see the color of cell display BLUE.

2.on the IE page,refresh the component by pressing F5.
You can see the content of the cell which is changed to BLUE is now display as BLANK

Then I unistall the JRE 6u24 and install JRE of other version.
The conclusion is that the problem only happens with version after 6U22(including 6U22).It
works well with version before 6u21(including 6u21).

So it seems a bug of JRE of version 6U22.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Try the work-around shown for [bug report 6996624](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6996624).

Comment: Hello Andrew Thompson. Thanks for your reply. It seems that my question is the same bug as bug report 6996624. But when would be the bug corrected?

Comment: The bug report is all the information I have.  Vote for it if is important to you.